# How to export JSON into DynamoDB using R

Tags: r, json, amazon-s3, cmd, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to add some data to my database in DynamoDB (Amazon Web Services). Since I want to add multiple rows, I created a (valid, I checked for that) .json file that looks like:

```
             {
 "Table_name": {
 "PutRequest": {
 "profid": ["100"],
 "page_url": ["www.test.nl"],
 "json": ["{blabla}"] 
               } 
               }
             }
```

When I execute the following command:

```
system(
 paste0('aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items ', .jsonfile)
```

I get the following response:

```
 Error parsing parameter '--request-items': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
    JSON received: {
    sh: 2: Table_name:: not found
    sh: 3: PutRequest:: not found
    sh: 4: profid:: not found
    sh: 5: page_url:: not found
    sh: 6: json:: not found
    sh: 7: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
```

Does anyone has any clue what goes wrong? And how to fix it, it is driving me nuts!